# Dynamic form input names allocated to $_POST

Tags: php

I have a form that has the name value of the input element dynamically populated from a mysql query.  Problem I am having is that I dont know to assign the value to a valid variable on form submission for later use, i cant declare the variable earlier in the scrip because i dont know it until the query is executed? how do i assign the name value to a $_POST variable?  thanks.

my code

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'jolly' ,'xxxx', 'jolly');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY name ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
?>                      
    <p align="right"><?php echo $row['name'] ?>:
    <input type="int" name="<?php echo $row['name'].'_score' ?>" />
    </br>
<?php } ?>
<p align="right">
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Next" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Although I don't seem to understand the logic of using input form name dynamic, but since it is your requirement, I would suggest something that may help. Have a hidden input field with name+count as the name and assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the value attribute of  tag like this

```
<input type="text" name="somename" value="<?php echo $row['name'].'_score' ?>">
```

i am sure this will help

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to assign an explicit name to an input. What you have to is distinguish the forms. When submitting the post, the entire form is submitted.

your.php:

```
<?php 
$var = $_post['data'];
...
>
```

form.php:

```
...
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'jolly' ,'xxxx', 'jolly');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY name ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
?>  
<form id = "form_<?php echo $row['name'].'_score' ?>" name = "form_<?php echo $row['name'].'_score' ?>" action = "your.php" method = "POST">                    
    <p align="right"><?php echo $row['name'] ?>:
    <input type="int" name="data" value= "<?php echo $row['name'].'_score' ?>" />
    </br>
<?php } ?>
<p align="right">
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Next" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to solve your conundrum would be to run the sql query before generating the html and storing the query results in an array / object / session. Once the values are stored you can generate the html but by that stage would know the names and values from the db call.

```
$con = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'jolly' ,'xxxx', 'jolly' );
$query = 'select * from `names` order by `name` asc';
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );
$data = array();

/* add content from db to storage object */
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) $data[]=$row['name'];

/* possibly save as a session? */
$_SESSION['names']=$data;



/* generate the html */
<form method='post' name='names' action='/path/to/script.php' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'>
    <?php
        foreach( $data as $i => $name ){
            echo "<p align='right'>{$name}<input type='int' name='{$name}_score' /></p>";
        }
    ?>
    <p align="right">
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Next" />
    </p>
</form>
```

if you stored the data in a session you should be able to access it in the form handler script if required.

Comment: thanks, i feel i am getting closer to what i need.  i need a variable assigned to the $_POST value so i can use it to update scores in the db.  does that make sense?